# get fields with reflection

Tags: c#, class, reflection

I want to get all fields that have null values but i aint even getting any fields:

```
  [Serializable()]
public class BaseClass
{
    [OnDeserialized()]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        FixNullString(this);
    }

    public void FixNullString(object type)
    {
        try
        {
            var properties = type.GetType().GetFields();


            foreach (var property in from property in properties
                                     let oldValue = property.GetValue(type)
                                     where oldValue == null
                                     select property)
            {
                property.SetValue(type, GetDefaultValue(property));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    public object GetDefaultValue(System.Reflection.FieldInfo value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value.FieldType == typeof(string))
                return "";

            if (value.FieldType == typeof(bool))
                return false;

            if (value.FieldType == typeof(int))
                return 0;

            if (value.FieldType == typeof(decimal))
                return 0;

            if (value.FieldType == typeof(DateTime))
                return new DateTime();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And then i have a class :

```
    [Serializable()]
public class Settings : BaseClass
{
    public bool Value1 { get; set; }
    public bool Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

But when i comes to

```
 var properties = type.GetType().GetFields();
```

then i get 0 fields, it should find 2 fields.

Is type.getType().GetFields() wrong to use ? or am i sending in the wrong class to the base class?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Type.GetFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx) methods returns all public fields. Fields that the compiler autogenerates for you are private, so you need to specify correct `BindingFlags`.

```
type.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

Answer (score 3):

The fields generated by the compiler corresponding to properties of your class have the [CompilerGenerated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilergeneratedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute. Also the compiler will generate `get` and `set` methods for handling these fields, depending on the declaration of your property.

From **CompilerGeneratedAttribute** MSDN documentation:

> Distinguishes a compiler-generated element from a user-generated element. This class cannot be inherited.

The name of these fields have the format `<PropertyName>k_BackingField`,the methods `set` and `get` names have the format `set_PropertyName` and `get_PropertyName` where PropertyName is the name of property.

For example, your `Settings` class is compiled as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class Settings : BaseClass
{
    public Settings(){}

    // Properties
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private bool <Value1>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private bool <Value2>k__BackingField;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public void set_Value1(bool value)
    {
        this.<Value1>k__BackingField = value;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public bool get_Value1()
    {
        return this.<Value1>k__BackingField;
    } 

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public void set_Value2(bool value)
    {
        this.<Value2>k__BackingField = value;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    public bool get_Value2()
    {
        return this.<Value2>k__BackingField;
    }
}
```

If you wish exclude this backing fields you can use this method:

```
public IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetFields(Type type)
{
    return type
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(f => f.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() == null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Value1` and `Value2` in your `Settings` class are properties rather than fields, so you'll need to use `GetProperties()` to access them.

(Using the `{ get; set; }` syntax tells the compiler that you want a property, but that it should generate the `get` and `set` for you, along with a hidden private field that contains the data.)